# 3 tables, 2 DBs, 1 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm a novice when it comes to Stored Procedures in SQL Server Management Studio. I have an application that I was told to make the following changes to using a stored procedure:

Step 1. User types in an item number.
Step 2. Customer name, address, etc. displays in the other fields on the same form.

There are 3 tables: Bulk orders, Small orders, and Customer information.

Bulk orders and small orders are in Database_1 and Customer information is in Database_2.

The primary key for small orders is the order number. A column in small orders contains the customer number for each order. That customer number is the primary key in the customer table.
The bulk orders table is similar.

I want to include a conditional statement that says: if order number is found in small orders table, show data from customer table that coorelates with that order number. I've attempted this multiple ways, but keep getting a "The multi-part identifier.... could not be bound" error.

I.E:

```
SELECT DB1.db.Customer_Table.Customer_Column AS CustomerNumber;
    IF(CustomerNumber NOT LIKE '%[a-z]%')
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM db.small_orders_table;
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM db.buld_orders_table;
    END
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you have a database link or any communication between server 1 and 2?  It's easier to do left joins and isnull functions than it is to try a conditional table select.

Comment: So is the customer no. passed as a parameter to your stored procedure?

Comment: They are on the same server. I'll try an isnull function.

Comment: I have no parameters within my stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it's 2 databases on the same server...in that case, you'll need to specify the fully qualified table name (database.schema.table) when referencing a table on the other database from where your stored procedure is found.

```
Database_1.db.small_orders_tables
```

Comment: I'll try this along with my isnull function.

Comment: And to compliment this answer, you can use Linked Servers functionality too (You need to link the servers first) so then you can use [ServerName].[Database].dbo.Table

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you cannot use aliases as variables. If you want to assign a value to a variable in order to test it, you have to do a SELECT statement like `SELECT @var = DB1.db.Customer_Table.Customer_Column FROM <YourTableFullName> WHERE <condition>`. Then you can use the @var (which must be declared before) for your test.

About the error you're experiencing, youre using fully qualified names in a wrong way. If you're on the same server (different databases), you need to specify just the database name on the top and then the schema of your objects. Suppose to have the following database objects on the Database1:

```
USE Database1;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
      id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , val varchar(30)
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (val) VALUES ('test1');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (val) VALUES ('test2');
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (val) VALUES ('test3');
GO
```

And the following ones on Database2:

```
USE Database2;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2
(
      id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , val varchar(30)
);
GO
```

Now, suppose that you want to read from the first table the value with `id = 2`, and then to apply your `IF`. Let's declare a variable and test it:

```
USE Database1;
GO

DECLARE @var varchar(30);

-- since you're on Database1, you don't need to specify full name
SELECT @var = val FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE id = 2;

IF @var = 'test2'
BEGIN
    SELECT id, val FROM dbo.Table1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- in this case the database name is needed
    SELECT id, val FROM Database2.dbo.Table2;
END
GO
```

Does it help?

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you for the input, and I'll try it out.